# (Scheme) Find if a item is a member of a leaf in a tree?

Tags: tree, scheme

I'm making a function that checks to see if a item is a member of a leaf in a tree.

This is what I have so far. It's not working right though. Some of the inputs that should be true are returning false. Help please?

```
(define (leaf-member? item tr)
 (cond
  [(empty-tree? tr) #f]
  [(leaf? tr)
      (if (equal? item tr) #t
          #f)]
  [else (leaf-member? item (cdr tr))]))
```

This is what it should return:

```
~(leaf-member? 'a (leaf 'a))
#t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close to the answer. To fix it you'll have to:

1. Compare the provided `item` with the actual *value* in a leaf (not with the leaf itself!)
2. Correctly advance the recursion over both subtrees. Notice that using `cdr` doesn't make any sense here, this is a *tree* we're traversing, not a list.

In both cases, use the appropriate accessor procedures. I'll try to guess their names, adapt them to your own implementation:

```
(define (leaf-member? item tr)
  (cond
    [(empty-tree? tr)
     #f]
    [(leaf? tr)
     (if (equal? item (tree-value tr))
         #t
         #f)]
    [else
     (or (leaf-member? item (tree-left tr))
         (leaf-member? item (tree-right tr)))]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! At least I was close.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not working with trees but lists. I say so because if you're in a tree then you search not the rest of the list ('cdr') but the left and right branches.

It would help if you post how you create a non-leaf tree to advise you better, but anyway your final statement shouldn't be this:

```
[else (leaf-member? item (cdr tr))]
```

but something like this:

```
[else (or (leaf-member? item (left-branch tr))
          (leaf-member? item (right-branch tr)))]
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't really know how to use trees so I was just kind of guessing...But, now I know that I should be searching the left and right branches and not the cdr or car.

Answer (score 0):

The code to find an item in a tree depends on the definition of a tree.  In particular, if you define a tree that is composed of subtrees, then that indicates how you will recurse on the tree.  As such, you need to start with the definition of 'tree' and 'leaf'.

Here is a full solution, w/o assuming a binary tree.

```
(define (make-tree item children)
  `(TREE ,item ,children))
(define (tree? thing)
  (and (list? thing)
       (= 3 (length thing))
       (eq? 'TREE (car thing))))
(define tree-item cadr)
(define tree-children caddr)

(define (make-leaf item)
  (make-tree item '()))
(define (leaf? tree) 
  (and (tree? tree) (null? (tree-children tree)))

(define (leaf-member? tester item tree)
  (and (tree? tree)
       (or (and (leaf? tree) (tester item (tree-item tree)))
           (let looking ((subtrees (tree-children tree)))
              (and (not (null? subtree))
                   (or (leaf-member? equal item (car subtrees))
                       (looking (cdr subtrees)))))))
```